# The Hibernate's PostgresUUIDType analogue in EclipseLink for mapping java.util.UUID to Postgres's "uuid" type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

When using Hibernate it is possible to mark field of JPA-entity with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")` if you want to map fields of type `java.util.UUID` to `uuid` type of PostgreSQL.

Is there such analogue in EclipseLink? 
Found solutions with writing your own converter (f.e.: http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/richard-yen/4-steps-using-uuids-jpa-postgresql) are not convenient.

Comment: With Hibernate 5, at least, it's not necessary to provide the annotation; Hibernate just maps it automatically. Have you checked whether EclipseLink handles it for you?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, I checked it. It gives an error that _column “uuid” is of type `uuid` but expression is of type bytea_. My eclipselink version is 2.5.2.